# PostgreSQL Search in Json format values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named property data where in it contains a JSON column like this one
[image]

Example JSON per row

```
["5236", "5826.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test 12", "Test 12", "", "56789.12384", "77878663.100239", "500", "Sample 1"]
["4427", "4606.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test10", "SAMP", "", "1123.44567", "12394.11235", "01", "SAMP"]
```

what I want to do is to have a query that can search inside the given data. for example I only want to display those data that has **`Test 10`**. I tried using the following query but receiving an error

```
SELECT * FROM property_data WHERE json_data LIKE '%Test 10%';
```

[image]

Anyone has an idea to search inside the JSON column? Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer with the sample data per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

If you only want to search a single array position (in this case index 5), you can use the `->>` operator ("Get JSON array element as text") ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)) to get the value in the position you're after and compare it (using `LIKE`) against your target value ("Test 10").

Example:

```sql
WHERE json_data->>5 LIKE '%Test 10%';
```

In context (the CTE is just for example purposes):

```sql
WITH property_data AS (
    SELECT
        '["5236", "5826.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test 12", "T..."]'::json AS json_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '["4427", "4604.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test11", "TP..."]'::json AS json_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '["4421", "4595.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test 10", "T..."]'::json AS json_data
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    property_data
WHERE
    json_data->>5 LIKE '%Test 10%';
```

With result:

```
                           json_data                           
---------------------------------------------------------------
 ["4421", "4595.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test 10", "T..."]
(1 row)
```

**Method 2**

Alternatively, if you just want to search the whole field, you can cast the column from `json` to `text` and then use `LIKE` as before.

Example:

```sql
WITH property_data AS (
    SELECT
        '["5236", "5826.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test 12", "T..."]'::json AS json_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '["4427", "4604.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test11", "TP..."]'::json AS json_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '["4421", "4595.0", "400", "Concrete", "0", "Test 10", "T..."]'::json AS json_data
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    property_data
WHERE
    json_data::text LIKE '%Test 10%';
```

With the same result as above (at least for this example).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. it works when searching string like test 10. but how about when searching numbers?

Comment: @AmyllaVimiar what do you mean searching numbers exactly? Like checking if a certain number is in the `json_data` column?

Comment: Yes, like if there's 400 in a given record. I figured it out I didn't changed the value.Thank you for the answer!

Comment: just have other question. how about searching on the json without defining the index where I want to search for it? because I'm searching dynamically with different values for example there are time wherein i can search for both Test 10, Test 1.

Comment: @AmyllaVimiar I made an edit the answer that includes a "Method 2", which works if you want to search the whole column or don't know which index position to search, does that address that question?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help